# Sql query for get count different tables

Tags: sql

I have three tables: country, table1,table2

`country_Table` will contain below data:

| country_code | country_name |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | America |
| 00002 | Australia |
| 00003 | Asia |
| 00004 | China |
| 00005 | Europe |
| 00006 | United Kingdom |

`Table_1` will contain below data:

| country_code | Document_No |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | 1 |
| 00002 | 1 |
| 00002 | 1 |
| 00004 | 2 |
| 00005 | 6 |
| 00005 | 6 |

`Table_2` will contain below data:

| country_code | Document_No |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | 1 |
| 00001 | 5 |
| 00003 | 5 |
| 00004 | 2 |
| 00005 | 6 |
| 00006 | 6 |

How do I count documents based on document_no for each country?
for example, I need the count of document no 1, document no 2, document no 3 for each country code if available.
Need to get output like below ( combining table1,table2) :

| country_code | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 00001 | 2 |
| 00002 | 2 |
| 00003 | 0 |
| 00004 | 0 |
| 00005 | 0 |
| 00006 | 0 |

Comment: For country `000112`, you have `1` as `Document_No` in `table_1`. And you also have, for country `000112`, `1` as `Document_No` in `table_2` What is the rule that leads to a `count` of `143` in the combined output? Do I have to expect more lines for country`000112` in the two input tables? Do I count the lines, or do I sum up the `Document_No` values?

Comment: @marcothesane Thanks for the response. For easy understanding, I have edited the question with simple numbers. While writing a query need to mention the document number. Based on the document number will get the count from each county

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using CTE. Please try this.

```
-- Taking the Count first by combining both the tables
WITH Count2 AS (
    SELECT country_code, COUNT(*) AS DocCount FROM (
        SELECT country_code, Document_No FROM Table1 WHERE Document_No = @Doc_No
        UNION ALL
        SELECT country_code, Document_No FROM Table2 WHERE Document_No = @Doc_No
    ) AS A
    GROUP BY country_code
)

-- Getting all the Country details with document count
SELECT CT.country_code, ISNULL(C.DocCount, 0) AS [COUNT] FROM country_Table CT
LEFT JOIN Count2 C ON CT.country_code = C.country_code
```

Comment: If you want to filter the Document_No, add where condition before grouping the data inside CTE.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/8949365/ananth-mk Thanks for the answer but I'm not able to get the logic here. actually in the output will be 2 columns one is area_code, and the second is count. The first column will be area_code and the next column will be count based on the document_no which we are giving in the query it's self

Comment: Updated the query with DocNo where condition and selected only needed column in the final query. Check now.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/8949365/ananth-mk Actually, I would like to know the logic here.